# pyspark: is `.cache` a lazy function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is `.cache()` a forward looking action that will apply to whatever Spark
dataframe is created at the end of a sequence?

Suppose you load a delta table, which is a lazy action, and then apply cache

```
sdf = spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/my/data")
sdf.cache()
```

Then you go on applying other lazy functions to that thing `sdf`.

```
sdf = sdf.filter("blah blah")
sdf = sdf.withColumn("myvar", blah())
sdf = sdf.select("more blah")
```

Still, no work has happened, lazy calc is waiting.

Then you touch the data frame and all of that lazy stuff happens.

```
sdf.show()
```

Should I expect `sdf` to be cached after this?

If no, should/will Spark disregard my first `.cache()` because it is a useless, unnecessary request?

Comment: calling `cache` marks the dataframe to be cached in the upcoming action. the data isn't cached unless an action is called. no matter how useless, spark will still try to cache. in your toy example, spark will try to cache `spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/my/data")`, not the final operation you did.

Comment: `cache()` is transformation and not an action , so yes it's a lazy operation, the df will be cached when the first action is called. and only you are doing one action ,then caching is not helpful. caching would be helpful , if you want to execute multiple actions on your df.

Comment: How can I tell what is cached, just to be sure.  It seems that @samkart and `eshirvana` have different answers.  One says first sdk from read is cached, while other says thing at end is cached

Comment: no, we're saying the same thing. the first action starts the caching mechanism for the marked dataframe. even if your action is after 10 transformations with the same df name, spark will cache the transformation that was marked.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Spark, the cache() operation is a forward-looking action that marks a DataFrame for caching when an action is executed. However, in your example:

```py
sdf = spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/my/data")
sdf.cache()
sdf = sdf.filter("blah blah")
sdf = sdf.withColumn("myvar", blah())
sdf = sdf.select("more blah")
sdf.show()
```

The transformations (filter, withColumn, select) applied to sdf after the cache() call will not be cached. Caching should be done after the transformations to avoid recomputation. When you perform an action like show(), Spark will recompute the DataFrame, and caching will occur at that point. The cache() happens only when an action triggers computation. But in your example, even if sdf is cached, every time you call an action you compte once again:

```py
sdf = sdf.filter("blah blah")
sdf = sdf.withColumn("myvar", blah())
sdf = sdf.select("more blah")
```

[I wrote an article that shows you how to cache wisely.](https://blog.det.life/caching-in-spark-when-and-how-367e77db454d)